# Update score in cocos2d drops framerate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing a game where I update the height the player has already gone. this is my code:

```
self.intScore++;
[self.lblScore setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.intScore]];
```

but when I set the lblScore with the current score, the framerate drops from 60fps to 40fps +-

I'm testing with an iPhone 4.

If I comment the [self.lblScore... then the framerate maintains in 60fps, but the score is not updated.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is what I done to solve this issue.

I had a function that updated the score every millisecond and yes, that was awful. So I changed the score updating to happen a little less.

I added this to the .h file

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) int slowScore;
```

and added this to my function on the .m file

```
if(slowScore < 5){
  slowScore++;            
}else if(slowScore == 5){
  self.intScore = self.intScore + 5;
  slowScore = 0;
} 
[self.lblScore setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.intScore]];
```

By doing that I was able to keep the same score but it gets updated leed times and by doing that, my framerate keeps nice at 60fps :)

+1 to @jonmorgan for suggesting the change to CCLabelAtlas.

I tested my new code with CCLabelTTF and CCLabelAtlas and both keep the framerate at 60fps, but running some tests with other parts of the code, CCLabelAtlas is performing much better.

Answer (score 0):

From the [cocos2D documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_c_label.html):

> Changing the string is as expensive as creating a new CCLabel. To obtain better performance use CCLabelAtlas

Use a `CCLabelAtlas` to improve your performance.

Comment: You're right, but the frames improved from 40fps to 42fps, the drop is still considerable. Can't find a way to improve this.